# Stack using Linked List in Swift

Tags: beginner, linked-list, swift, stack

I made this implementation of a stack in Swift that stores its elements as a linked list. It seems to work perfectly well, but I’m wondering how I can improve it to follow the best practices of the language.

```
struct StackList<T> : CustomStringConvertible {
    private var first: StackNode? = nil // The topmost node in the stack

    /// Add a new element to the top of the stack
    /// - parameter newElement: the new element to be added
    mutating func push(_ newElement: T) {
        let newElement = StackNode(newElement);
        newElement.next = first;
        first = newElement;
    }

    /// Remove and return the topmost element from the stack
    /// - returns: Optional containing the removed element, or nil if the stack was empty
    mutating func pop() -> T? {
        guard let first = first else { return nil }

        let poppedElement = first.element
        self.first = first.next
        return poppedElement
    }

    /// The number of elements in the stack
    var size: Int {
        var count = 0
        var current = first

        // Traverse the list
        while current != nil {
            count += 1
            current = current!.next
        }
        return count
    }

    /// Textual representation of the stack
    var description: String {
        var output = ""

        // Traverse the list
        var currentNode = first;
        while let thisNode = currentNode {
            if output != "" { output += ", " }  // Add commas between elements
            output += String(describing: thisNode.element)

            currentNode = thisNode.next
        }

        return "[\(output)]"
    }

    private class StackNode {
        var next: StackNode? = nil
        var element: T

        init(_ element: T) {
            self.element = element
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks already quite good and clean. Here are my remarks:

> ```
> private var first: StackNode? = nil // The topmost node in the stack
> ```

An optional value is initalized to `nil` by default, so

```
private var first: StackNode? // The topmost node in the stack
```

is sufficient. And with a different variable name it becomes self-explaining:

```
private var top: StackNode?
```

There are trailing semi-colons at some places, these are not needed in Swift.

Here

> ```
>     let newElement = StackNode(newElement)
>     newElement.next = first
>     first = newElement
> ```

you pass one property of the new node as parameter of the init method, and
set the other via accessor, which looks asymmetric to me. With

```
private class StackNode {
    var next: StackNode?
    let element: T

    init(_ element: T, next: StackNode?) {
        self.element = element
        self.next = next
    }
}
```

this simplifies to

```
    let newElement = StackNode(newElement, next: first)
    first = newElement
```

or even

```
    first = StackNode(newElement, next: first)
```

Note also that the `element` property in `StackNode` can be a *constant.*

A better property name for

> ```
> /// The number of elements in the stack
> var size: Int
> ```

might be `count` – that is what all Swift collection types use. The forced
unwrap in

> ```
>     // Traverse the list
>     while current != nil {
>         count += 1
>         current = current!.next
>     }
> ```

is safe, but can even be avoided with

```
    // Traverse the list
    while let node = current {
        count += 1
        current = node.next
    }
```

A common practice is to put the implementation of protocols into separate
extensions:

```
extension StackList: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String { ... }
}
```

*Naming:* `class StackNode` is defined within the `StackList` “namespace,”
so you can simply name it `Node`. And I would name `StackList` just
`Stack` – it is an implementation detail that it uses a linked list.

#### Further suggestions

Make `StackList` conform to `Sequence`. A simple implementation would be

```
extension StackList: Sequence {
    func makeIterator() -> AnyIterator<T> {
        var current = first
        return AnyIterator {
            guard let node = current else { return nil }
            defer { current = node.next }
            return node.element
        }
    }
}
```

That allows to enumerate all elements easily:

```
for item in stack { print(item) }
```

In addition, you can use it in the `description` method which then simplifies
to

```
extension StackList: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        return "[" + self.map { "\($0)" }.joined(separator: ", ") + "]"
    }
}
```

Implement a `peek()` method to get the top element without removing it,
and an `isEmpty` property.